# MySQL query that returns all records from "first day" of the current month & year?

Tags: mysql

Need to return all records from "first day" of the current month & year? (ex.. need all 11/01 records)
Something like this:

```
(YEAR(INVOICE_DATE) = YEAR(NOW()) 
AND 
(DAY(INVOICE_DATE) = “Current Month 11/01”
```

- PS: I need the Year & Day values to be dynamic in the query.
- INVOICE_DATE is a Date/Time type

Comment: when we say 'from "first day"' we are meaning datetime values that fall sometime on the first day of the month. that is, we don't want to return datetime values from the 2nd of the month, or the 3rd.  Because if we wanted to include those, we would just say we want to return all rows "from the beginning of the month", if we meant to return all rows in November.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(
  YEAR(dateColumn), 
  MONTH(dateColumn), 
  '01'
) = CONCAT(
  YEAR(NOW()), 
  MONTH(NOW()), 
  '01'
)
```

Comment: I like this idea, but when I tried it, it returned 0 records?

Comment: It might be the "TIME" portion of my DATE/TIME field that is causing it not to match/return any records?

Comment: i'm not a fan of this approach, because it forces the optimizer to evaluate the expression for *every* row in the table, a full scan. it disallows the optimizer from making effective use of a range scan operation, using an index with `dateColumn` as the leading column. For optimal performance, we prefer predicates on bare columns. (For trivial sets, of course we won't notice any performance difference. But at scale, the difference becomes excruciatingly obvious. This suggest we  adopt a pattern that allows 1) effective use of index, and that 2) works for *any* range on DATETIME values.)

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to reference the bare column, which will allow MySQL to make use of a range scan operation with a suitable index

```
 FROM t
WHERE t.invoice_date  >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
  AND t.invoice_date   < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

We can test the expressions (on the right side of the comparison operators), in a `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS bdt
     , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS edt
```

return:

```
bdt         edt
----------  ----------
2019-11-01  2019-11-02
```

and see that the net effect is the same as if we had written:

```
 FROM t
WHERE t.invoice_date  >= '2019-11-01 00:00:00' 
  AND t.invoice_date   < '2019-11-02 00:00:00'
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** *When I tried it, it returned 0 records? It might be the "TIME" portion of my DATE/TIME field that is causing it not to match/return any records?*

**A:** Doing the comparisons as shown in the query above, with datetime greater than or equal to midnight of the first, and datetime less than midnight of the second, that should return datetime values anytime on the first.

datetime values like this would satisfy the condition: '2019-11-01 08:15', '2019-11-01 16:20', etc.

We can verify with simple test. We expect two of these datatime values to be returned, and the third to be excluded:

demonstration:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ( SELECT           '2019-11-01 08:15' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS invoice_date
         UNION ALL SELECT '2019-11-01 16:20' + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
         UNION ALL SELECT '2019-11-02 00:00' + INTERVAL 0 DAY 
       ) t  
 WHERE t.invoice_date  >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   AND t.invoice_date   < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

returns:

```
invoice_date         
-------------------
2019-11-01 08:15:00  
2019-11-01 16:20:00
```

---

Before we muck with expressions to generate the date boundary values, we should test with literals, e.g. `'2019-11-02'`.

```
 FROM t
WHERE t.invoice_date  >= '2019-11-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
  AND t.invoice_date   < '2019-11-02' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Once we get that working, then we can work on developing expressions to replace the literals.

Comment: When I tried it, it returned 0 records? It might be the "TIME" portion of my DATE/TIME field that is causing it not to match/return any records?

Comment: doing the check... datetime greater than or equal to midnight of the first, and datetime less than midnight of the second, that should return only datetime values from anytime on the first. datetime values like this would satisfy the condition: '2019-11-01 08:15',  '2019-11-01 16:20', etc. We can verify with test cases. FOLLOWUP section added to answer.

Comment: the TIME portion of the `DATETIME` datatype is not an issue. The question said the column was `"Date/Time"` type... in MySQl, the datatype keyword is `DATETIME`, no slash.  Are we certain that the datatype of the `invoice_date` column is `DATETIME`?  We aren't storing date-ish/time-ish strings in a VARCHAR column, and doing wonky string comparisons rather than actual DATETIME comparisons? Providing the actual column definition (actual SQL syntax, not a description), along with sample data, would go a long ways towards clarifying the spec. We are as far as we can go with the info provided.

Comment: if the spec is to return datetime values that fall on days other than the first of the month, then we would need to modify the upper bound. the query strategy is the same... identify the lower bound (earliest datetime) and upper bound (earliest datetime that is outside the range we want to return) and do the >= and < comparison.  if we want all rows since the lowerbound, we can omit the upperbound check. but without sample data, and an example of the expected return, all we have to go on is an imprecise description.

Comment: TIME is not needed, just need the records where Invoice Date is 11/01/2019

Comment: this answer demonstrates the normal query pattern for getting a range of DATETIME column... figure out the values to use for the lowerbound and upperbound, and then do comparisons e.g. `invoice_dt >= '2019-11-01 00:00:00' AND invoice_dt < '2019-11-02 00:00:00`.  That's the normal pattern, we can use it to to get a range since the beginning of the month, to get a range of first 10 days in a month, the past week, an hour and 15 minutes, ... we can re-use that same *exact* pattern, over and over. The trick is getting expressions that will dynamically produce values for the upper and lower bound.